# convert ucs-2 to utf-8 in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, ucs2

Hello I used visual baisc 2010 and usb modem  to sent at commands " ussd " by SerialPort "AT+CUSD=1" my problem when recive result get ucs-2 like this

> +CUSD: 0,"00430075007200720065006E007400540069006D0065002000690073003A002000320031002D004A0055004C002D0032003000310038002000310036003A00320036",72

how i can convert to utf-8

Comment: While I don’t have a copy of VB2010 to test, you probably want [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) with a parameter of `CP_UTF8`.

Comment: UCS-2 is the predecessor of UTF-16, so it's basically a subset of UTF-16. All characters in the former are the same in the latter, so you shouldn't need to convert anything there. Your string is however represented in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that string, because of its composition, is in [BigEndianUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) format.
This encoding format is available from .Net FW 3.5+ / VS 2008.
The .Net version in use is more important than the Visual Studio version, though.

So, let's try to parse this string and see what comes out of it.

```
Dim input As String = [SerialPortOutput]

input = input.Replace(ChrW(34), "")
Dim ucs2 As String = input.Split(","c)(1)

Dim HexBytes As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)()
For i As Integer = 0 To ucs2.Length - 1 Step 2
    HexBytes.Add(Byte.Parse(ucs2.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
Next
```

Now, transform the List of bytes from `BigEndianUnicode` to a standard .Net string.

```
Dim output As String = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(HexBytes.ToArray())
```

The output string reads:

> "CurrentTime is: 21-JUL-2018 16:26"

To convert it to UTF8, if really needed (Internet transfer, maybe), get the encoded array of bytes:

```
Dim UTF8Bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output)
```

Comment: Nice answer! You beat me to it ;). || Note to menasoft: `BigEndianUnicode` is UTF-16 with big-endian byte order.

Comment: thanks alot
but when use as function i get error 

`Private Function usc2string(ByVal input As String) As String
 
            Dim ucs2 As String = input.Split(","c).Skip(1).Take(1).First()

            Dim HexBytes As New List(Of Byte)()
            For i As Integer = 0 To ucs2.Length - 1 Step 2
                HexBytes.Add(Byte.Parse(ucs2.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
            Next
            usc2string = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(HexBytes.ToArray())

    End Function`
Error message :  Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @menasoft  I don't have this error. I tested it with your `Function` and the string you posted. It's parsed correctly. Note: the string should contain the `+CUSD: 0,` part. Also, does it contain an hardcoded `"` delimiter internally? I stripped it from the string (as you can see in the post). But if it's actually there, it must be cut out before parsing the string. I'll edit the code if this is the case. Can you tell me which instruction generates an error for you? .

Comment: @Jimi  now it run when remove like this double quotes input.Replace("""", "").Replace(" ", "")

Comment: @menasoft  Yes, I reproduced the error, too. I'll make an edit to the code.

Comment: "UTF8, if really needed…maybe": Maybe is a real question. It is very likely that wherever this `String` is going, there will be a way of telling it to do any needed conversion to UTF-8.