# Convert String to Byte Array in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, byte

My aims is to do the following

1. Convert UNIX Time (i.e. 1582818012) to HEX String (i.e. 5E57E2DC) - Solved
2. Convert HEX String to Byte Array (i.e. 5E57E2DC) to (i.e. &H5E, &H57, &HE2, &HDC) - **Pending**

How can I do the conversion?

So I this case the result will be something like below:

`Dim oneByte() As Byte = {&H5E, &H57, &HE2, &HDC}`

`oneByte(0)= 5E`

`oneByte(1)= 57`

etc...

Comment: See the code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458379/7444103). From `Dim HexBytes As List(Of Byte) ...`.

Comment: integer.Parse() with NumberStyles.HexNumber to convert the string, BitConverter.GetBytes() to generate the bytes, Array.Reverse() to change the order to big-endian.  Do keep in mind that this code stops working somewhere near the year 2038, google "y2k38 bug" to learn why.

Answer (score 1):

Using a couple of standard methods

```
    Dim ut As Integer = 1582818012
    Dim uts As String = Convert.ToString(ut, 16)
    'look at oneByte in hex
    Dim oneByte() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(ut).Reverse.ToArray
    '           (0) &H5E    Byte
    '           (1) &H57    Byte
    '           (2) &HE2    Byte
    '           (3) &HDC    Byte
```