# How to convert string array of hex value to an array of byte in vb.net

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I have a string of array in Hex. for example

`dim Result(0) As String = "5D 05 03 00"`

How can I convert this value to become a byte array?

For example I want my final answer as bytarray(0) = 55, bytarray(1) = 54 etc...

I try using

```
                For Each s As String In Results(0)
                    stringArrayBytes.AddRange(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s))
                Next
                Dim bytarray() As Byte = stringArrayBytes.ToArray
                Command_Window.cmdWindow.AppendText(bytarray(0) & Environment.NewLine)
```

But the answer produce

bytarray(0) = 53 (which i want it to be 5D)

bytarray(1) = 68 (which i want it to be 05)

bytarray(2) = 32 (which i want it to be 03)

bytarray(3) = 48 (which i want it to be 00)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458379/7444103). `Step 3` if the values are separated by a space. Do you want to get the values as a Byte array or you just want to split the string instead? It appears you're using these values as string in the end.

Comment: I think you want `Dim bytarray = results(0).Split({" "c}).Select(Function(a) Convert.ToByte(a, 16))`.